# Double Action on a Single HTML Form

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I understand that I cant do a double action on a single form. I am using a form for login purposes and need one of the form inputs on another file `header.php`. How is it possible for me to do so in PHP or JavaScript?

This is my code if u guys need a reference:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="patient" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
    <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="clinic" id="RadioGroup1_1" />
    ....
    <input name="login" type="submit" class="loginButton" id="login" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

The `$loginformaction` variable is an action for login. So i need to add another action to the form that will help me get the radiogroup input into another file.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what page the action is going to initially, within that action page, just use php's [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) to include `header.php`. Then you will still have access to the `$_POST` array in `header.php` as well.

Comment: it goes back to the same page actually...so how do i include it??

Comment: If you don't put the `action` attribute in the form, it should refresh the current page on form submission. Then in php on that same page, you can `include_once` header.php so both the starting file and `header.php` can read the form data posted.

Answer (score 0):

Include header.php in the script that is given in the `action`-attribute of the form:

```
include 'header.php';
```

Comment: In the script that is mentioned in the `action`-attribute of the form.

Comment: <?php $loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];...action attribute of the form goes back to the same file....so how can i include?